# Both call and apply produce the same result for String.prototype.toUppercase when passing an array

Tags: javascript

I usually see that we should use an array in apply method and array of arguments in call method:

If I do the following (call method would return undefined):

```
var namelist = {
   f:'first name',
   l:'last name'
}
function func(a,b){
   console.log(this[a]+' '+this[b])
}

func.call(namelist,['f','l'])
//undefined undefined

func.apply(namelist,['f','l'])
//first name last name
```

But, look here both call and apply method works:

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(['a','b','c']) //returns 'A,B,C'
String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply(['a','b','c']) //returns 'A,B,C'
```

Why the call method is working?

If I do use like this:

```
String.prototype.toUpperCase.call('a','b','c')
//this would return 'A' only.
```

Comment: Can't answer now because the question is closed but I'd say that your array is being converted to a string in both cases to be used as the `this` argument and `['a','b','c'].toString() === 'a,b,c'`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `call` and `apply` is the *context* for the function, the value of `this`.

> But, look here both call and apply method works:
>
> ```
> String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(['a','b','c']) //returns 'A,B,C'
> String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply(['a','b','c']) //returns 'A,B,C'
> ```

Yes, that's not at all the same as your example. You're only passing one argument into each of `call` and `apply`, so they are identical. You're passing the same `this` with both methods. They're identical invocations.

> ```
> String.prototype.toUpperCase.call('a','b','c')
> ```
>
> //this would return 'A' only.

Yes, because you're passing only `'a'` as `this` to `toUpperCase`. It would do the same thing (if it weren't an error) with `apply('a', 'b', 'c')`, again, because you're passing only `'a'` as `this` to `toUpperCase`. The difference is that `apply` raises an error if you try to give it more than two arguments.

---

Original answer:

That isn't how you pass arguments with `call`.

Use `func.call(namelist, 'f', 'l')`.

`apply` takes an array of arguments. `call` just takes the arguments.

Comment: I think OP's actual question is why do both `call` and `apply` produce the same result in `String.prototype.toUpperCase`

Comment: yeah, that's how call method supposed to be work but I am giving the example of String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(['a','b','c']) and why this is working...

Comment: They do the same thing because because the **are** the same thing. They're identical invocations. You're passing your array as `this` to both methods. There is no difference between `apply(x)` and `call(x)`, they're identical. The difference is only in how they accept arguments. `apply(x, [y])` and `call(x, y)` are identical.